# Transfer Azure VM Snapshots to different account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, snapshot, msdn, vhd

Let me start by saying I've Googled and Bing-ed all over and haven't quite found what I'm looking for.
I have a snapshot of a VM contained in our company Azure subscription. Part of the perks we also get at our company are individual MSDN Azure accounts (they're part of a different subscription). I'm trying to transfer (well, clone actually) the VM snapshots from the company subscription to the individual subscription. That's the problem. Now, the details of what I've tried.
Transferring resources from one subscription to another isn't that difficult, but the issue is that the two subscriptions have to be part of the same directory, and also the user needs to be a contributor to both subscriptions (I don't want to have to make each individual a contributor to the company azure account and then remove them just to move snapshots around), and lastly, transferring snapshots to different locations (they exist in east us right now, but some of them need to be in other locations) seems to be problematic as well.
If all else fails, I can download the VHD and upload it to each individual account, but that's a lot of downloading and a lot of uploading (would be great if I could do it all while keeping the file in Azure and not have to download it locally).
So the question essentially boils down to:
**How can I transfer/clone snapshots in azure to different accounts in different locations without modifying subscriptions?**

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is, since this is a common use case. Have you tried just copying the snapshot from the source subscription's storage account to the new subscription's storage account with one of the available 1st-party Azure command line tools (such as azCopy)? This does not require any download/upload, since copying happens within the storage service. And no "same directory" needed; you just need the storage keys. FYI You cannot copy a snapshot to a snapshot. It must be copied to a new blob (and copying just a snapshot doesn't really make sense anyway).